# Как правильно организовать запись в MongoDb?

Tags: yii2, mongodb

Есть задача потихоньку перейти с `MySQL` на `mongodb` сейчас, что бы не сбивать работу сайта пока переводим только товар, c дублированием его пока в две базы.
Вопрос в следующем есть две модели `Goods` и `Addfields` в форме сохранения модели `Good` есть некоторые свойства модели `AddFields` в монго формируется следующий документ

```
"_id":"5a02d9afb2d45753294debc6",
"title":"Костюм женский 'Маргарита'",
"slug":"goods-Kostum-zenskij-Margarita",
"discription":"<p>Цвет: темно синий, светло бежевый, голубой, ментол, сиреневый, бордовый. Оттенки могут отличаться.</p>"
"product_id": 2576,
"addField":[
  "quote":"Цвет: темно синий, светло бежевый, голубой, ментол, сиреневый, бордовый. Оттенки могут",
  "size1":"48-50;52-54",
  "shop": "0",
  "composition":"дайвинг",
  "country":"Украина",
    "delivery":"3-5 дней",
    "site":"bole-ro",
  "winter""0",
  "spring":"0",
  "summer":"0",
  "fall":"0"
]
```

`addField` этого документа формируется как из свойств модели `Good` так и `Addfields`. И если с Goods мне все более или мение понятно и получилось. То с `Addfields` есть проблемы вот так я оформил запись монго (структура `Addfield` такая `'id'`,`'id_goods'`,`'key_field'`,`'value'`)

```
$product=Products::find()->where(['product_id'=>$this->id_goods])->one();
        $key=$this->key_feild;
        $product['addFeild'][$key]=$this->value;
        $product->save();
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
```

но получаю следующую ошибку

> Indirect modification of overloaded element of
>   common\models\mongo\Products has no effect

ругается на эту строку

```
$product['addFeild'][$key]=$this->value;
```

что я делаю не так и как правильно ?

Comment: Я в PHP совсем ничего не понимаю... но чисто интуитивно: у Вас, в первой строчке, написано `id_gods` с одной "о", а по логике вещей должно быть две.

Comment: @Дмытрык это артефакт в написании здесь, я использую не совсем тот код которые есть в приложении

Comment: А не думали Doctrine для mongo использовать?  Класс, который написан в yii под mongo не очень удобно сделан, особенно если нужны вложенные документы. Ну это не ответ, а так повод для размышлений..

Comment: @OlyLad а что это можно ссылку для документацию